# mock static method call in private static final field of the class

Tags: java, junit, powermock, easymock

I have a basic `Widget` class that uses utility class `Utils`

```
public class Widget {

    private static final String BUTTON_KEY = Utils.getMessage("btn-key");

    public boolean comp() {
        String specialKey = Utils.getMessage("special-key");
        return specialKey.equals(BUTTON_KEY);
    }

}

class Utils {

    public static String getMessage(String key) {
        return key + " : message";
    }

}
```

I want to create a test for `comp` method.

My test looks like this

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Utils.class)
public class WidgetTest {

    private Widget widget;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockStatic(Utils.class);
        widget = new Widget();
    }

    @Test
    public void testComp() {
        expect(Utils.getMessage("btn-key")).andReturn("btn-key : message");
        expect(Utils.getMessage("special-key")).andReturn("special-key : message");
        replayAll();
        assertFalse(widget.comp());
        verifyAll();
    }

}
```

The test fails with

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call:
Utils.getMessage("btn-key")
Usage is: expect(a.foo()).andXXX()
```

If I remove method call in the constant field (and consequently remove expectation for it) test succeed.

What is the problem?

Comment: I'm afraid to say but your `Widget` class is not testable due to static initialization of `BUTTON_KEY`.

Answer (score 2):

#### General comment

Please read this philosophical comment before the rest of the answer.

I often encounter badly testable code. We have Spring, we have Dependency Injection, why do we still feel urged to use static methods and utility classes?

When you feel like using PowerMock, consider first if a small refactoring of your code would not help you better.

The pure fact that you need to mock your method implies that the method is not really *static*. Well, maybe `Math.sqrt()` or `Assert.assertEquals()` are good examples of really *static* methods.

On the other hands, some methods which might seem "static" at the first glance betray you as soon as you start thinking about testing, such as `LocalDate.now()`. In your tests, the thing you need to have static is the current date, not the method :)

There are lot of good ideas in here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/148049/105827

---

#### Your problem

The problem is that the static initializer of the `Widget` class is called *before* you start defining expectations.

You may see this if you add this code anywhere to the `Widget` class:

```
static {
    System.out.println("Widget.static");
}
```

and this code to the beginning of the `WidgetTest.testComp()` method:

```
public void testComp() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("test method");
    ... // the rest of the method
}
```

When you run the test, the output is like this:

```
Widget.static
test method
```

It means that `BUTTON_KEY = Utils.getMessage("btn-key")` is executed *before* `expect(Utils.getMessage("btn-key")).andReturn("btn-key : message");` and that PowerMock is rightly complaining about the missing behavior definition.

---

#### Possible fast solution

If you want to keep your static logic, there is a quick workaround. Do not initiate your BUTTON_KEY in the static initializer block, but lazily.

I don't like it very much, I still prefer completely getting rid of static calls.

I left in the code the test `println()`s so you may see the order of calls.

```
public class Widget {
    private static String BUTTON_KEY;

    static {
        System.out.println("Widget.static");
    }

    public boolean comp() {
        String specialKey = Utils.getMessage("special-key");
        return specialKey.equals(getButtonKey());
    }

    private static String getButtonKey() {
        synchronized (Widget.class) {
            if (BUTTON_KEY == null) {
                System.out.println("Widget is calling Utils.getMessage(`btn-key`)");
                BUTTON_KEY = Utils.getMessage("btn-key");
            }
        }
        return BUTTON_KEY;
    }
}

class Utils {
    public static String getMessage(String key) {
        return key + " : message";
    }
}
```

The order of calling is then this:

```
Widget.static
test method
Widget is calling Utils.getMessage(`btn-key`)
```

Comment: well the method is static because it is a part of utility class, that allows to get message from `.properties` file. So basically I have to either remove constants or something...

Comment: @lapots See my edit - I provided a link to how to turn your Util class into something testable. Or just search google: `Java how to turn static utility class into testable class`. It's better investment of time to fix your class so it is testable **without** PowerMock, rather than trying to do workarounds. PowerMock itself is a workaround enough :)

Comment: the problem is that utility class is not mine but external dependency. at most can do is to move initialize to some variables inside method

Comment: "The pure fact that you need to mock your method implies that the method is not really static". To the point. +1.

Comment: @ShanuGupta well in some classes I do indeed to mock it as static and also mock it as is. but nothing I can do about it. only workarounds